# How do I develop application for USSD mobile codes?

Tags: mobile, gsm, ussd

I want to develop application on top of **USSD** codes.
I have a web app that shows the status of a request. Here, i need to create an USSD app that will take application no. from user and then server will show the status of application. Please help.

Comment: This is too broad to be a SO question really.  You need to make a small app that uses AT commands or Windows Mobile Broadband API (if win desktop).  There are equivalent apis for Win Universal and Android.  If you look in the relevant tags on this website, there are a lot of pointers about how to use AT commands or the Mobile Broadband API.

Comment: @SList. Thanks for your response. Actually what i want is how these mobile operators using this service. 
My thinking is, there could be some web service endpoint exposed against that USSD code. So, there should be some layer which receives the request, understood it, hit the end point and the format the output in USSD message. 

I want to know, how that layer works. And how i can implement my layer or is there any generic API for that.

Comment: USSD is embedded in the mobile network at the same level as SMS.  The USSD server is inside the core of the mobile network.  The advantage of that is, that you don't need an internet connection to use USSD, only a GSM network.  That's how the mobile operators use it, in my experience.  Of course, the USSD protocol can also be implemented at the web level if you want.

Comment: @SList, can you show me how to start developing a beginners USSD App in c# or Java , am new in this ?